# For a React app, can the build process not create a JavaScript map file?

Tags: reactjs

If an app is created using React's official `create-react-app hello-world`, and building it with `npm run build`, I often do:

```
npm run build && rm -f build/static/js/*.js.map
```

because when the files are transferred to the server using `sftp`, I just use

```
put -r .
```

to put everything there, and the `js.map` file is huge, like 2.7MB for a small project.

It also takes time to build it too, so instead of building it and removing it, is there a way to just not build it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*For anyone coming to this question in 2018 and later :*

Add the following line in a `.env` file at the root of your project.

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP = false
```

Comment: It's nice that you provide credits. I'd recommend to write them as a comment to shorten the answer.

Comment: **_Credits:_** [Dan Abramov explained sourcemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211646/for-a-react-app-can-the-build-process-not-create-a-javascript-map-file/43219478#43219478) well, and [Luis Armando wrote this awesome comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211646/for-a-react-app-can-the-build-process-not-create-a-javascript-map-file#comment92683663_43219478) which game us a link to a discussion in github. [Here is the original answer](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2787#issuecomment-360431080) and I just post it here to save your time.

Comment: What is the point of `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP`? Why is it default to True?

Comment: @NickSmith "A sourcemap is a mapping between the generated/transpiled/minified JavaScript file and one or more original source files. The main purpose of sourcemaps is to aid debugging. Basically, if there’s an error in the generated code file, the map can tell you the original source file location." You can [learn more with an example here](https://trackjs.com/blog/debugging-with-sourcemaps)

Comment: @AhmadMaleki I see, thanks! So basically you should always leave it out before deploying to prod?

Comment: @NickSmith I'm not sure if it's a **must** but I always do it myself.

Answer (score 10):

Create React App author here.
Just delete `.map` files (or ignore them when syncing).

They are not essential (although many find them useful to debug production issues). Your app will work without them.

No, there is currently no way to skip building it. We might add this in the future.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your answer here.
[Take a look at this conversation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2787) you were involved about GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false.

Answer (score 5):

Open `package.json` file form the root directory of your project,

Locate `"scripts" > "build"` and add prefix `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to the value. It should look like below

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
```

This will disable the generation of map file in the build process.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want create map files, just modify webpack config for `build` script: set `devtool= false` in `webpack.config.prod.js`. More detail about webpack [devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

Note: Before modify that webpack config file, you need to `npm-run-eject`. See [detail](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject)

Answer (score 0):

.map files are there for ease of development to 'map' your minified file/s to your source code. Depending on your build process, you should modify your configuration so that it does not produce source-maps.

Comment: so if the app was created using React's official `create-react-app hello-world`, then there probably is a known place you can edit to have it not create the file?